# Listing elements of an array as strings trouble? (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, string

```
public class Club
{
    private ArrayList<Membership> members;

    public Club()
    {
        members = new ArrayList<Membership>();

    }

    public void join(Membership member)
    {
           members.add(member);
    }

    public int numberOfMembers()
    {
         return members.size();
    }

    public void listMembers1() {
        for (String memberDetails: members){
            System.out.println(members.toString());
            }
    }
}
```

I have another class called 'Membership' which is used to add membership details. The problem I am having is when I try to list members I am given an error in the 'for statement' area, which says Membership cannot be converted to String.

Thanks

Comment: For better help, please post a valid [mcve],. code we can (almost) compile and test, as well as the complete unabridged error message.

Comment: `for (Membership memberDetails: members){` and `System.out.println(memberDetails.toString())`  Learn how loops work please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`members` is a collection of `Membership` objects, thus your `for-each` loop should be using a `Membership` object rather than `String`:

```
for (Membership memberDetails: members){
     System.out.println(members.toString());
}
```

Also, if you have not already, I suggest creating a custom `toString()` method in your `Membership`class, otherwise it will print something like `Membership@7852e922`.

Comment: no need for `.toString()` when you print an object its `.toString()` is called by default

Answer (score 0):

members is a collection of membership (ArrayList) objects hence for-each loop expects Membership as the data-type for individual object and not String.

All the Java classes inherit toString() method from Object class and if toString() is not overridden in a class to print desired string representation of the object then it by default prints (class name + @ + hashcode of the object). Hence if you would like to see a desired string representation of object in question then it’s class should override toString() method.